# Django: how to specify verbose_name with _meta without importing model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is a simple model definition, using an import for a foreign key:

```
from companies.models.owner_company import OwnerCompany

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner_company = models.ForeignKey(OwnerCompany,
                                      on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                      verbose_name=OwnerCompany._meta.verbose_name)
```

Let's say that now, I need to define it without importing the `OwnerCompany` object.
In this case, how would you define the verbose_name?

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner_company = models.ForeignKey('companies.OwnerCompany',
                                      on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                      verbose_name='???')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "proxy object" that will for `str(..)` return the verbose name. For example:

```
from django.apps import apps

class VerboseName:

    def __init__(self, app_name, model_name=None):
        if self.model_name is None:
            self.app_name, self.model_name = app_name.split('.', 1)
        else:
            self.app_name = app_name
            self.model_name = model_name

    def __str__(self):
        return str(apps.get_model(self.app_name, self.model_name)._meta.verbose_name)
```

Then we can use this `VerboseName` object:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner_company = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.OwnerCompany',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=VerboseName('companies', 'OwnerCompany')
    )
```

or with a dot:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner_company = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.OwnerCompany',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=VerboseName('companies.OwnerCompany')
    )
```

The name of the app is however here required.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. To be picky, is there a way to be a little bit more DRY by avoiding to write `'companies.OwnerCompany'` then `('companies', 'OwnerCompany')` in the model definition?

Comment: @DavidD.: yes, we can slightly alter the logic to split on the dot, see edit.